# KML raster not showing images when using another users machine

Tags: raster, kml, google-earth, superoverlay

I have converted some geotiff's into raster KML file packages, (which consist of a KML file and two folders - images and files). I have created these KML's as superoverlay KML files.

I am able to successfully load the KML into Google Earth EC on my computer and see the output.

I have directed a different user on another PC to load the KML file - which they can, however it only takes them to the extent of the data and does not show the images associated with the KML. The tree structure on the right also does not show the associated files as per on my machine.

Additionally, the user in question that is having the problem has full read/write access to the folder in which the KML exists and also the images + files subfolders.

Why do the images not show for the other user, but they do for myself?

Sample KML contents:

```
<Document>
<name>e_100y_max_d</name>
<visibility>1</visibility>
<NetworkLink id="kml_1">
<name>e_100y_max_d1</name>
<Region>
<LatLonAltBox>
<north>-21.73210771550464</north>
<south>-21.96438026963675</south>
<east>116.50377196418752</east>
<west>116.25510594725066</west>
</LatLonAltBox>
<Lod>
<minLodPixels>256</minLodPixels>
<maxLodPixels>-1</maxLodPixels>
</Lod>
</Region>
<Link>
<href>files/e_100y_max_d1.kml</href>
<viewRefreshMode>onRegion</viewRefreshMode>
</Link>
</NetworkLink>
</Document></kml>
```

Addtionally, the KML files in the 'files' subfolder, contain references to the images as per here:

```
<href>../images/e_100y_max_d1_2_1_0.tif</href>
```

Comment: It seems the links to the images inside the KML are broken. Check the links in your KML file.

Comment: the links are fine, because they work for myself. Also I have confirmed with another user and it works. Thanks for the feedback, but I don't believe the problem exists in the KML file itself.

Comment: Did you provide the images to the other user and they are using the same paths as defined inside the KML?

Comment: hiya, I have edited the question to include the KML contents and also confirmed the users folder access permissions. .

Comment: Where are the images?  Are they referenced by the KML files in the network link?  What do those KML files look like?

Comment: the images are in an 'images' subfolder. There are several dozen additional kml files in the 'files' subfolder. These kml's reference the images folder in the same way as above... sample here     <href>../images/e_100y_max_d1_2_1_0.tif</href>